# What are Bevel Edges

Tags: edit-mode, edges, bevel

8 i can see different types of edges in edit mode. I know what Sharp and Seam edges do. But what do the bevel edges do and why do the bevel edges has different color?

Thank you for your time :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [bevel weight](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/custom_data.html#bevel-weight) is visualized in light blue (similiar to the teal *sharp*).

You can edit the weight in *Edit Mode* by selecting edges and pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open up the edge menu (which can also be accessed through the *3d View*'s header menu bar). 
In the edge menu choose *Edit Bevel Weight*. The bevel weight can also be accessed in the Properties Panel <kbd>N</kbd> of the *3D View*. The bevel modifier can use the bevel weight to restrict the beveling.

[image: bevel weight]

Comment: I am aware that the manual link is still a TODO. I have included it for the future.